# I would have to have been listening outside the door to have heard what was being said

Tags: subjunctive-mood

The above (question) is perfectly good English grammar, and its meaning is clear. (At least to me).

It seems to express a possible condition. (It doesn't really say whether or not I was listening outside the door).

Can anyone break this down for me grammatically? What is the grammar here? It looks like would + have + Present Perfect Continuous?.

Comment: To me, it implies that the speaker was _not_ listening and therefore could not hear what was being said.

Comment: @KateBunting, it is usually used in that context, but does not strictly mean the person was not listening. I used to use similar constructions when asked awkward questions by my parents.

Comment: @Peter, I think you likely used it to *imply*  you weren't even if you were.  As Kate says, "it implies" not "it means".

Comment: I usually use *imply* in the strict sense of being a logical consequence. In the softer sense of the word I agree.

Comment: Surely the sense is "I did not hear; I would only have been able to do so if I had been listening outside the door".

Answer (score -2):

First, there's the subjunctive mood constituted by the use of the modal verb 'would', denoting personal conviction.

Then, 'to have been listening' follows as a perfect, progressive infinitival clause

Next, 'to have heard': another perfect infinitival clause

You can think of the two infinitival clauses as complements to the matrix VP. Or I might have to ask my syntax professor next week if the first 'have to' following the modal is the main VP in your sentence. Will get back to you if no real syntactician does before me!